# The column xxx was specified multiple times for table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, db2, alias

I am trying to adapt a db2 simple query to SQL SERVER. This query is working fine on db2

```
select * 
from pb_console.users u 
join ( 
     select * from pb_console.users_user_role j join  
     pb_console.users_roles r on j.role_id = r.role_id) as jj 
on jj.user_id = u.user_id
```

on sql server it fails with error:

```
The column 'ROLE_ID' was specified multiple times for 'jj'
```

I have tried removing role _id from the left table of the join as:

```
select * from pb_console.users u join ( 
    select user_id, role_rif from 
    pb_console.users_user_role j join (select role_id, role_name from 
pb_console.users_roles) r 
on 
j.role_id = r.role_id) as jj on jj.user_id = u.user_id
```

but resulting in.

```
The column 'role_id' was specified multiple times for 'jj'.
```

I have also tried using a different alias for the first role_id, with no success.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is raised because the `ColumnName`**ROLE_ID** is present in both the table `pb_console.users_user_role & pb_console.users_roles` so try to specify the columns that are only required as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM pb_console.users u 
join ( 
     SELECT J.RoleID,J.User_ID FROM pb_console.users_user_role j 
     JOIN pb_console.users_roles r ON j.role_id = r.role_id) AS jj 
on jj.user_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from pb_console.users
```

Syntax should not be used.

The static way to handle this :
In SSMS editor, right clic on the pb_console.users table to get the "select *" detailled syntax... And override alias names as previously told by Joby or Sandip.

The dynamic way :
Create a stored procedure to retrieve the current structure of the table to build an sql statement run through "EXECUTE"... Harder way...

Answer (score 1):

You got error : `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'` in your code because you have not specified any column in select statement, please specify required column in your below query statement

```
select from pb_console.users_roles
```

It should be like

```
select role_id from pb_console.users_roles
```

For Error:

> The column 'role_id' was specified multiple times for 'jj'.

try with **alias.columnname** in all select statement

```
select * from pb_console.users u join ( 
    select j.user_id, j.role_id from 
    pb_console.users_user_role j join (select role_id, role_name from 
pb_console.users_roles) r 
on 
j.role_id = r.role_id) as jj on jj.user_id = u.user_id
```

Comment: I have edited the query cause there were missing columns, see the question

Comment: still column is missing in the second block with this statement : select from pb_console.users_roles

Comment: OK sorry, see the question now, veen with column names it doesen't improve

Comment: let me check, i have given solution for : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Comment: try with alias.columnname in all select statement

Answer (score 0):

please do not use from * instead of columns name in * and column name may be conflict with each others.

in my case as bottom code:

```
select a.*,b.*,a.x1 from a
join b on b.fkId=a.pkid
```

a.* and a.x1 are conflict with each others because a.* has contains a.x1 column and the return table have 2 columns with x1 name.