# How To Avoid Group By Which included Aggregate functions in Select Statement

Tags: sql-server

Good Morning to everyone.,

I am trying develop an attendance report which shows In & OUT time base on Log details which I don't want to group by **Device** No which gives me repeating values for Each entries. Is their any way to avoid Group by Device Name. Query as below. second part of the query is just same with T2.alias

```
SELECT 
T1.[PUNCH DATE], 
T1.[TOKEN NO], 
T1.[NAME],
T1.[DESIGNATION], 
T1.[DEPT.], 
T1.[PROJECT NO.],
T1.[F.CODE.],  
T1.[W.DAYS], 
T1.[SHIFT STARTS], 
T1.[SHIFT ENDS], 
T1.[BREAK MIN.] ,  
MIN(T1.[TIME IN])'TIME IN',
T1.[DEVICE IN]'DEVICE IN',
MAX(T2.[TIME OUT])'TIME OUT',
T2.[DEVICE OUT]'DEVICE OUT',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MI, T1.[TIME IN], T2.[TIME OUT]))-DATEDIFF(MI,(0),T1.[BREAK MIN.]),0),108) 'TOT.HRS.',

T1.[DAY/NIGHT]

FROM(SELECT

EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Date 'PUNCH DATE',  
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Token_No 'TOKEN NO', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Name 'NAME',
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Designation 'DESIGNATION', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Dept_No 'DEPT.', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_No 'PROJECT NO.', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_FCode 'F.CODE.', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_W_Days 'W.DAYS', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Starts 'SHIFT STARTS', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_End 'SHIFT ENDS', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Break_Mins 'BREAK MIN.' ,  
MIN(EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time) 'TIME IN',
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Device_No 'DEVICE IN',
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Type 'DAY/NIGHT' 
FROM
EMP_Event_Log JOIN
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation ON EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Token_No = QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Token_No AND QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_To IS NULL OR
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Date<=QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_To
WHERE 
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Date =@Local_@SDate AND 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Type='DAY' AND
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Token_No = QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Token_No AND QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_No=@Local_@FCode

GROUP BY
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Token_No, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Name,
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Date, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Designation, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Dept_No, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_No, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_FCode, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_W_Days, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Starts, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_End, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Break_Mins,
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Device_No,
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Type

HAVING
(MIN(EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time)<>'00:00:00.0000000' OR MAX(EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time)<>'00:00:00.0000000') AND
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), MIN(EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time),113)AS TIME)<>CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),MAX(EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time),113)AS TIME))AS T1 

JOIN(

SELECT
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Date 'PUNCH DATE', 
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Token_No 'TOKEN NO', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Name 'NAME',
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Designation 'DESIGNATION', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Dept_No 'DEPT.', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_No 'PROJECT NO.',
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_FCode 'F.CODE.',  
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_W_Days 'W.DAYS', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Starts 'SHIFT STARTS', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_End 'SHIFT ENDS', 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Break_Mins 'BREAK MIN.' ,  
MAX(EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time) 'TIME OUT',
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Device_No 'DEVICE OUT',
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Type 'DAY/NIGHT'
FROM
EMP_Event_Log JOIN
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation ON EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Token_No = QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Token_No AND QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_To IS NULL OR
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Date<=QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_To
WHERE 
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Date=@Local_@SDate AND 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Type='DAY' AND
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Token_No = QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Token_No AND QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_No=@Local_@FCode

GROUP BY
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Token_No, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Name,
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Date, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Designation, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Dept_No, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_No,
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_FCode,  
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_W_Days, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Starts, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_End, 
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Break_Mins,
EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Device_No,
QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Type

HAVING 
(MIN(EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time)<>'00:00:00.0000000' OR MAX(EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time)<>'00:00:00.0000000')AND
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), MIN(EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time),113) AS TIME)<>CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),MAX(EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time),113) AS TIME))T2 on T1.[TOKEN NO]=T2.[TOKEN NO]
GROUP BY 
T1.[PUNCH DATE],
T1.[TOKEN NO],
T1.[NAME],
T1.[DESIGNATION], 
T1.[DEPT.], 
T1.[PROJECT NO.], 
T1.[F.CODE.], 
T1.[W.DAYS], 
T1.[SHIFT STARTS], 
T1.[SHIFT ENDS], 
T1.[BREAK MIN.] ,  
T1.[TIME IN],
T1.[DAY/NIGHT],
T2.[TIME OUT],
T1.[DEVICE IN],
t2.[DEVICE OUT]
ORDER BY T1.[TIME IN]
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague, specifically: "don't want to group by Device No which gives me repeating values for Each entries". Why exactly you don't want to group by `Device No`? What happens when you don't group by it?

Comment: @Alex It gives me multiple entry for some employees if the punch multiple time which I want only Fist IN and Last Out Of the Day. Thanks

Comment: why are you trying to delete all code?

Comment: @Alex I'm sorry It was a mistake. while editing the code my PC had sum issue & stuck.  Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

### My understanding:

- `Device No` is a non key property of `EMP_Event_Log` record.
- You want to get `Device No` associated with specific "Punch Time".

### Solution:

The easiest way to get to it is via [Window Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY 
    -- This is where your current Group By columns go
    EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Token_No, 
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Name,
    EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Date, 
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Designation, 
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Dept_No, 
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_No, 
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_FCode, 
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_W_Days, 
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Starts, 
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_End, 
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Break_Mins,
    -- You can now exclude EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Device,
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Type
    ORDER BY 
    EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time ASC ) AS FirstIn,
    -- Same as above except ASC becomes DESC
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ..... ORDER BY EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time DESC ) AS LastOut
FROM
    EMP_Event_Log JOIN
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation ON EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Token_No = QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Token_No AND QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_To IS NULL OR
    EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Date<=QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_To
    WHERE 
    EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Date =@Local_@SDate AND 
    QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Shift_Type='DAY' AND
    EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Token_No = QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Token_No AND QTB_EMP_Project_Allocation.EMP_Project_No=@Local_@FCode
) AS Processed
WHERE ( FirstIn = 1 OR LastOut = 1 ) AND EMP_Event_Log.EMP_Punch_Time <> '00:00:00.0000000' AND NOT( FirstIn = 1 AND LastOut = 1 )
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: What sort of error? What is your version of SQL Server?

Comment: Row no is Specified for multiple time for Processed (Version 2008 R2)

Comment: You should do a little "Googling" ;) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633908/the-column-xxx-was-specified-multiple-times-for-table/43634157 . What this means is that you should explicitly list your columns like in your original query instead of using a `*`.